# Reading Point object under different environnement

Tags: geodjango, development, geos

## The problem

I create a GIS model which works fine on my dev environnement. When I push my app to my production environnement I get an `GEOS_ERROR`

```
GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Invalid HEX char.
```

here is a sample that I run on shell :

#### My model

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Loc(models.Model):
    geolocalisation = models.PointField(srid=4326, blank=True, null=True)
```

#### The shell script

```
from galerie_cms_integration.models import Loc, Groupe
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, Point
l = Loc()

l.geolocalisation = Point(12.4604, 43.9420)

l.save()
Loc.objects.all()
```

#### The output (dev env)

```
>>> from galerie_cms_integration.models import Loc, Groupe
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, Point
>>> l = Loc()
>>> 
>>> l.geolocalisation = Point(12.4604, 43.9420)
>>> 
>>> l.save()
>>> Loc.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Loc: Loc object>]>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> c=Loc.objects.filter(geolocalisation='Point(12.4604 43.9420)')
>>> c
<QuerySet [<Loc: Loc object>]>
```

#### The output (prod env)

```
>>> from galerie_cms_integration.models import Loc, Groupe
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry, Point
>>> l = Loc()
>>> 
>>> l.geolocalisation = Point(12.4604, 43.9420)
>>> 
>>> l.save()
>>> Loc.objects.all()
GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Invalid HEX char

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 226, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 62, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 842, in results_iter
    row = self.apply_converters(row, converters)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 827, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, self.connection, self.query.context)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 325, in from_db_value
    value = Geometry(value)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py", line 65, in __init__
    g = wkb_r().read(force_bytes(geo_input))
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/io.py", line 154, in read
    return wkb_reader_read_hex(self.ptr, wkb, len(wkb))
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 162, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/threadsafe.py", line 57, in __call__
    return self.cfunc(self.thread_context.handle.ptr, *args)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lampesCMS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/errcheck.py", line 32, in check_geom
    raise GEOSException('Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "%s".' % func.__name__)
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKBReader_readHEX_r".
```

## Description of environnements

System:
Dev = Macosx El Capitan 10.11.6
Prod = Raspbian GNU/Linux buster/sid

Same database (same connection for the moment, to exclude this).

In each environnement, I am working under Virtualenv.

Dev and Prod has the same libs :

```
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.11.6'

>>> from django.contrib.gis import geos
>>> geos.geos_version()
b'3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6'

$ pip freeze
cmsplugin-filer==1.1.3
diff-match-patch==20121119
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.11.6
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.4.5
django-debug-toolbar==1.8
django-filer==1.2.8
django-formtools==2.1
django-import-export==0.5.1
django-mptt==0.8.7
django-polymorphic==1.0.2
django-sekizai==0.10.0
django-treebeard==4.1.2
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.7
djangocms-attributes-field==0.3.0
djangocms-column==1.7.0
djangocms-googlemap==1.1.1
djangocms-installer==0.9.7
djangocms-link==2.1.2
djangocms-snippet==1.9.2
djangocms-style==2.0.2
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.5.0
djangocms-video==2.0.4
easy-thumbnails==2.4.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
geopy==1.11.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
html5lib==0.9999999
jdcal==1.3
odfpy==1.3.5
olefile==0.44
openpyxl==2.4.8
Pillow==4.2.1
psycopg2==2.7.3.1
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
tablib==0.12.1
tzlocal==1.4
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode==0.4.21
xlrd==1.1.0
xlwt==1.3.0
```

I build the GEOS library from source to get the same in the two env, but I always get the same error.

**[edit] add this output if it's help.**
here is the postgis version output :

```
POSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.5.1-CAPI-1.9.1 r4246" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

As you can see it's not the same GEOS version as the python module. But it should not be the reason of error because the both environnement (dev and prod) are using the same database (for this test purpose)
**[end edit]**

The only difference I can see is the hardware :

- Raspberry 2 : ARMv7 Quad Core 32bit Processor.
- Imac9,1: Intel Core 2 Duo 64bits.

The libgeos is  [arm] compatible https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=geos
so I am not sure it's an architecture trouble.

### Raw data output

```
postgres=# SELECT * from public.galerie_cms_integration_localisation;

 id | nom | adresse | ville | geocodeAdresse |                  geolocalisation                   
----+-----+---------+-------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------   
  6 |     |         |       |                | 0101000020E610000024287E8CB9EB28407F6ABC7493F84540
```

Comment: Same libs in the same versions? Are both systems 64bit?

Comment: thanks for your interest. as you can read in the last output libs are the same . but you right my Imac is 64bit and the RPI2 is 32. is it the reason of the error？is all 32bits will get the same geos error ？

Comment: I asked for the versions (the numbers) of the libs, there might be important changes! I have no idea what the error might be, but 32 vs 64 might be worth investigating if you cannot figure it out otherwise.

Comment: Libgeos 3.6.2. I first used 3.4.2 but to be closer to my dev env I tried to used the same version which is 3.6.2 on my MacOS. Still get the same error. I will try with a RPI3 which is build with a 64 bit chip. I will edit the question to give detail about that.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the raw database? (the field that stores the geometry). Also, check this thread: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GEOS-Question-with-Geometries-tt3753506.html#none

Comment: i will give you the raw output soon. the link you share looks to be the same issue but without answer. in my case its a weird behaviour cause i can create geom from prod and read it from dev. i never could read from prod.

Comment: I added the raw output from a created  point by my prod.

Comment: if i try to get different output GEOSGeometry (ewkt, ewk, ...) format it's still get me the same error. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#output-properties

Comment: For what it's worth, I have heard, though only anecdotally because I have windows, of problems with libgeos 3.6.2 on macOS that were solved by using 3.6.1.

Comment: thanks but  I don´t have trouble on MacOs env(its my dev) I have trouble on my Raspbian env.

Comment: well, I installed all my stuff under RaspberryPi 3 (64bit) under another distrib (HypriotOS/armv7  4.4.50-hypriotos-v7+ GNU/Linux) and it's work. Don't know if it's cause by the 32bit system) but it work so, thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue (Identical Setups on different architectures), and also tried with different OS (fedora 26,27, Raspbian, OpenSUSE) for aarch64 and arm32, over 3 different boards: Raspberry Pi 2, 3 and Pine64

The solution I've just found was installing Django 2.0 vía pip, as it's not yet available in Fedora 27 aarch64 repos, on the Pine64.

I imagine that it should also work on the Pi because the file were the "GEOSWKBReader_readHEX_r" error originated ( /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 226 ), does no longer exist on that path.